# EF 4.1 N Tier ASP .Net confusion

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, n-tier-architecture

I hope you can help me out with any advice, it'd be greatly appreciated.

I've been using EF 4.0 for a while now using the following object context management technique  http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx . I have a fairly simple setup with a web project connecting to a BLL connecting to a DAL. The web and BLL reference the DAL Entity objects. It's been functioning fine but it seems very slow. It's an ASP .NET Webforms application that uses an existing database model (i.,e not code first) and points to a SQL Server 2005 DB.

Anyway, I'm now revisiting the architecture as we're getting complaints over screen to screen performance. I've done most of the UI enhancements possible but I think it's just the Save, Redirect and Load using EF that's the sluggish point now.

The site is a series of quote pages for car insurance. I'm now hoping to do create the relevant objects in session, i.e, page 1 create quote object, populate fields, page 2, add X additional drivers, page 3 add claims /convictions and then save the objects to the database. The users will be able to save and exit at any point in the quote process so the save won't always be at the end. We also need to be able to load page 1's info and update it in memory when they click Next and finally update the DB when they're ready to finish the quote.

At the moment, we're doing the retrieve and saves on the same page. How would you advise we move to the storing in session/final commit?

I've trawled through various msdn pages and I'm having trouble putting it all together into the latest 'best practice' for 4.1 for this fairly simple application. I've looked at Julie Lerman's videos but her n'tier only did a simple retrieve and 'Add', suspiciously leaving out the Update section as I suspect it is not straightforward. Do you think I should use Self Tracking Entities (I've read that people are having multiple issues with this but maybe their architecture is more complex?) or some other way of storing the EF objects in session and making the changes

Any help/ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing data in Session can be an effective method to minimise IO, but it's not a simple decision. You shouldn't put large amounts of data in Session State and we can't tell from your description what kind of volume of data you're talking about, or the number of concurrent active sessions.

There's also the question of your Session State provider. If you're using a single server, you'll probably use in-process Session State, which is quick, but if you have lots of users and lots of data, you can soon run into memory pressure issues.

If you're using a web farm, you'll have to use shared Session State, possibly using the SQL Server Session State provider, so you'll end up reading from and writing to a database on every interaction, which could be worse.

However, step 1 is to make sure you understand the problem. Don't make assumptions about where your performance problems are and try to redesign those. Use profiling or instrumentation techniques to identify the real bottlenecks and concentrate your efforts on those.

You might be surprised as to where your problems lie. It may well simply be a database optimisation issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Steve. I'm aware of the differences in session state provider. We're storing in SQLServer at the moment will be looking to move to AppFabric eventually. I've used tools like Jetbrains dotrace and SQL profiler but think there must be a better way of doing n-tier ASP .net with EF 4.1. Has anybody got any ideas or sample architectures that actually work?

Comment: It's too broad a question, Rick. There are many potential designs and the one that you currently use is as valid as any. I have worked on ASP.NET solutions that use both DB-persisted and session-state based repositories with equally good performance in each case. Indeed, we've just modified an app to go the other way (from state-based to DB-persisted). One is not necessarily inherently better than the other. You need to find what's right for *your* application and that depends on its detailed characteristics.

Comment: Thanks Steve but I'm just looking for a simple example of N-tier ASP .NET working with EF 4.1 that works on a final commit and can CRUD without problems?

Comment: BTW, for anybody interested I had a nightmare with STEs. Complete pain. I ended up reviewing it all again and realised that I had put my CompiledQuerys in a class that would only exist during a page's lifecycle! Complete facepalm! You should at least move the CompiledQuerys to a static class in your application that will exist app-wide to gain the benefits of compiled queries! Thanks Steve for the nudge that something was wrong.